# After changing website template into drupal images don't load

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I'm changing a site template into the drupal theme.
I put the header in `html.tpl.php` and body in `page.tpl.php` and also set `.info` file but the page doesn't load properly and image of the site don't show in browser. 
it seems to me with these settings and Since I still haven't changed the static content. it should work same as static version if so what would be the problem?

HTML code:

```
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modernizr.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
       <div id="wrapper">       
        <div class="header-wrapper header-alt2">
                <div class="works-thumb">
                  <img src="../img/works/works-8.jpg" alt="Project Name">
                  <div class="works-title">                            
                   <h4>
                     <a href="single-project-image.html">Project Name</a>
                   </h4>                            
                  </div>
                  <a href="portfolio.html" title="Category Name" class="works-icon"><i        class="icon-play"></i></a>
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <p>Project Name Description</p>   
                    <div class="overlay-icons">
                      <a href="../img/works/works-full8.jpg" title="Preview" class="works-preview fancybox tooltips"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                      <a href="project-image.html" title="Permalink" class="works-link tooltips"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                      <a href="portfolio.html" title="Category Name" class="works-cat tooltips"><i class="icon-play"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>            
         </div>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

`.info` file:
package, core and ..

```
      stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
      scripts[] = js/modernizr.js
```

and region

`html.tpl.php` file:

```
      ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en">
        <head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
          <?php print $head; ?>
          <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
          <?php print $styles; ?>
          <?php print $scripts; ?>
        </head>
        <body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
          <?php print $page_top; ?>
          <?php print $page; ?>
          <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

`page.tpl.php` file:

```
       <div id="wrapper">       
        <div class="header-wrapper header-alt2">
                <div class="works-thumb">
                  <img src="../img/works/works-8.jpg" alt="Project Name">
                  <div class="works-title">                            
                   <h4>
                     <a href="single-project-image.html">Project Name</a>
                   </h4>                            
                  </div>
                  <a href="portfolio.html" title="Category Name" class="works-icon"><i        class="icon-play"></i></a>
                  <div class="overlay">
                    <h4></h4>
                    <p>Project Name Description</p>   
                    <div class="overlay-icons">
                      <a href="../img/works/works-full8.jpg" title="Preview" class="works-preview fancybox tooltips"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
                      <a href="project-image.html" title="Permalink" class="works-link tooltips"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                      <a href="portfolio.html" title="Category Name" class="works-cat tooltips"><i class="icon-play"></i></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                 </div>            
         </div>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your all images in to

> /sites/all/themes/yourthemename/images

folder.

Then change the image path in page.tpl.php like this:

> /sites/all/themes/yourthemename/works-8.jpg

instead of using:

> ../img/works/works-8.jpg

Comment: I actually changed the "../img/works/works-8.jpg" with "<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme(); ?>/img/works/works-8.jpg". Thanks for your reply.